# Send video to multiple displays with different content, using a single video output

Tags: multiple-monitors

Is it possible to output different video content to multiple displays from a generic single video output connector, by e.g. connecting some sort of hardware to the port?

I'm not looking for multiple graphics cards solutions.

Comment: You should define which video port you are talking about (DVI,VGA,HDMI,composite)? In theory it may be possible with time multiplexing, but I'm not aware of any hardware for that

Comment: That will be DVI or HDMI. I read about TripleHead2Go from Matrox, this might be what I am looking for, but I still need to find out more..

Answer (score 1):

There are cards with special connectors that actually can be split to several outputs (e.g. some cards from Matrox works like this). This is by specific design and is not generic for every card.

In your case you seem to want to send out e.g. an 1280x(720*2) signal, use hardware to "split it in half" and send each halves to different displays.

First, there is a limitation in how high resolution your graphics card can present, so it is likely that you might have to compromise on the individual screen resolutions.

Such a hardware splitter is not trivial and will most certainly be a lot more expensive than a graphics card with support for multiple outputs, but yes: they do exist. See e.g. http://www.icpads.com/videowall.htm.

The key terms to look for to find more products such as the linked ones above are "**video wall splitter/converter/controller**".

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, the link is also very useful. I am still looking for the possibility whether I want to open different application (in this case browser) for each display or use single browser but open all information to it and let the hardware split the information...